# How do you say you like something to some extent? For instance Can you say "I like football some."?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language, adjective-degrees

**A: How much do you like football?**

**B: I like it some.**

I know **"I like it some"** would not be correct nor idiomatic, however in my native language we have a very practical way of saying it this way (literally), if you like something not very much nor very little.

I thought of other ways of saying it such as **"I like it to some degree"** but this sounds too wordy.

Same is true when it comes to saying the degree of feeling ill. For istance:

**A: Are you ill?**

**B: I feel ill some.**

It is incorrect, I know that, but that is exactly the degree I want to say. Not too ill, nor very well.

So, I wanted to ask: Is there a practical way of saying the level of liking something or feeling in a particular way which is to the degree of **"some"** without being too wordy?

Comment: some, a bit, a little bit, somewhat, to some degree, to some extent. Is that enough? :)

Comment: @Lambie, So can I say: "I like football some." Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, it's fine when you speak. But not in formal writing. Yeah?

Comment: It sounds like 'trailer park American' to me. It's not something any Brit would ever say, nor, I imagine, any educated American.

Answer (score 2):

"I like it some." seems understandable, but dialect - perhaps American South.  It is probably best avoided by a learner, as there are other much simpler ways to express moderation:

> I quite like it.

> I somewhat like it.

> I'm quite ill.

> I'm rather ill.

> I'm not at all well.

<sub>I think I remember a film in which a character says "My dog barks some".  I forget the context, but it wasn't meant to represent clear or plain speech</sub>